# How can I find i1 and i2 in function of Vg in this circuit?

Tags: ac, differential

Given the attached schema I'd love to find the analytical temporal and frequency expressions for the current in the 2 branches: i1 and i2.
R0, R1, R2, C1, C2 and Vg(t) are given. In the time domain can you show me how to set the system of differential equations that will bring me to the solution? Once I have the system it shouldn't be a problem to solve it using for instance odeint in Python.
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Might I recommend Kirchhoff's Laws?

Comment: Sure you can, however even with your recommendation I'm still not able to find the solution. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

> Once I have the system it shouldn't be a problem to solve it using for instance odeint in Python.

If your goal is to get a numerical solution for these currents, just use a simulator that's designed for solving circuits and let it work out the equations for you.

There are many simulators out there based on the original SPICE simulator, and many of them are available for free. Any of them can solve this very simple circuit.

Comment: I think this is not an answer, the goal is: *"I'd love to find the **analytical** temporal and frequency expressions for the current in the 2 branches: i1 and i2"*

Comment: @Huisman, but they also imply (in the part I quoted) that they'd be happy with a numerical solution.

Comment: To the heart of the matter... why walk when you can catch a train or better still, fly +1

Comment: @Andyaka The question is *"How can I find i1 and i2 in function of Vg in this circuit?"* and is elaborated by the part i quoted before. So, I wonder this answer is to the heart. But let OP make the call. BTW, to stay in your analogy, to catch a plane, you'll need to **learn to walk** first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's solve for \$\text{I}_0\left(t\right)\$. The input voltage can be written as follows:

$$\text{V}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\cos\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$

In the complex notation we can write:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\hat{\text{u}}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\tag2$$

The input impedance is given by:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\text{R}_0+\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}+\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}\tag3$$

So, the input current is given by:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space0}=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\tag4$$

So, in the end, we get:

$$\text{I}_0\left(t\right)=\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|\cdot\cos\left(\omega t+\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\right)\tag5$$

Comment: Where did you get the information that the input signal is a sinusoid? That's never said in the posted question.

Comment: Thank you! Afterwards, how can I get i1 and i2?